# ffmpeg command not executing properly after reformatting pc and installing the newest version

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a set of images from frame 1 to frame 1241 in frame step 10

and run the following in cmd:

> ffmpeg -start_number  1 -framerate 25 -i
>   C:\MATLAB-Source-Files/Result_Eye/result_%05d.jpg -vf
>   framestep=10,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -c:v mpeg4
>   C:\MATLAB-Source-Files/eye_result.mp4 -y

I intend to create an mp4 in frame step 10. It used to work before but now it seems to not cover the frames. I get a resulting mp4 but 0:00.

[Here is the result of executing the command in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L5wb.png)

Comment: What are the initial file names?

Comment: file names are in the format - result_00001.jpg, result_00011.jpg, .... , result_01241.jpg

Comment: You need to supply [all frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48225047/5726027) to ffmpeg and ffmpeg will drop all but each 20th frame.

Comment: I did this ffmpeg -start_number 1 -framerate 25 -i result_%05d.jpg -vframes 124 -vf framestep=10,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -c:v mpeg4 result.mp4 -y    still got 0:00

Comment: Are `result_00002.jpg` `result_00003.jpg` ..present?

Comment: I think that was the problem! I only have 1,11,21,31,etc..  Is it really required to include all of it? I specified the frame step by 10 and I assume it should only include 1, 11 etc.. Anyway to make this work without having to include the in-between images?

Comment: Use the method [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer). Skip the duration lines